# Calling a function after .text

Tags: jquery, text, append, fadein

I'm having a problem calling a function after appending text in order to have the #line2 fadeIn nicely. If I run this code, everything after.append is printed as text, including the second nested function. http://jsfiddle.net/jJyL4/1/

```
$("#line2").append("<div id='normal-text'></div>") {
    $("#line2").text("SOMETEXT").fadeIn({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#line2").text("SOMETEXT").fadeIn(4000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jJyL4/4/

.fadeIn() function will automatically set opacity property to 1, you can just set duration.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#line2").append("<div id='normal-text'></div>");
$("#line2").text("SOMETEXT").fadeIn({opacity: 1}, 1500);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jJyL4/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect, you can't write

$("#line2").append(...) **{ ... });**

The bold part there is not allowed in JavaScript.

Now, if you have this HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="normal-text">TEXT</div>
    <div id="line2"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that after calling

```
$("#line2").append("<div id='normal-text'></div>");
```

You will end up with this:

```
<div>
    <div id="normal-text">TEXT</div>
    <div id="line2">
        <div id="normal-text">TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure you want that. Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
$("#line2").hide().text("SOMETEXT").fadeIn(1500);
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pL8Bu/)